# Is aws-iam-authenticator still needed with EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've created a cluster (eks.3) through the console and then used `aws eks update-config` to generate the kubeconfig configuration. I immediately had access to the cluster through `kubectl` but the EKS user guide talks about aws-iam-authenticator as if it was required. Is this still needed? If not, how is authentication happening after cluster creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Amazon EKS uses IAM to provide authentication to your Kubernetes cluster[...], **but it still relies on native Kubernetes Role Based Access Control (RBAC) for authorization**. [...] All permissions for interacting with your Amazon EKS cluster’s Kubernetes API is managed through the native Kubernetes RBAC system.
> [EKS userguide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html)

So you don't necessary need the aws-iam-authenticator. The aws-iam-authenticator maps IAM user and roles to the native [Kubernetes Role Based Access Control (RBAC)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/) for authorization. So theoretically it should be possible to just use the RBAC. However the official documentation only refers to IAM authentication. So I would advice to use that as well. I'm not 100% sure if a missing aws-iam-authenticator could cause problems with service based policies. Stuff like granting a pod access to a s3 bucket.

> When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, the IAM entity user or role, such as a federated user that creates the cluster, is automatically granted system:masters permissions in the cluster's RBAC configuration.
> [EKS userguide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html)

That is why your user has access to the EKS cluster.